# How to call an action on the app route from any component without having to pass it everywhere?

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to be able to open a login modal from any component without having to pass it through the component hierarchy each time I need it.

The openModal action on the application is the same as in the modal cookbook in the guides :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modalName) {
      return this.render(modalName, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I would like to avoid :

```
{{my-component openModal="openModal" otherArgs=args ... }}
```

Plus
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal(modalName) {
      this.sendAction('openModal', modalName);
    }
  }
});
```

I could use a service injected in each component, but then how to call the openModal action on the application route from the service ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try `this.send('openModel')`? `send` and `sendAction` are different.

Comment: I believe that in the context of a component "send" can only be used to call actions in that same component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a service with a function like this:

```
openModal(){
    this.container.lookup('route:application').send('openModal');
}
```

Then you only need to inject this service to every component that needs to launch the modal and call this function.